# How to bind java service in native code?

Tags: android, android-binder

Is it possible to bind java services in pure native code? Essentially, calling this part of code in under native C code

```
Intent i = new Intent(); 
i.setClassName("com.example.fooservice", 
    "com.example.fooservice.service"); 
bindService(i, clientConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not directly. However, you could accomplish it calling up to your `NativeActivity` via JNI.

Comment: I think the tricky part for that is to get the clientConnection's callbacks, is that doable via JNI as well?

Comment: Also, why android won't allow native code to access java android service.. that seems a very reasonable thing to do if you are writing a native app..

Comment: Android's dev model is to use the runtime, which provides a standardized way for apps to be entered and controlled. Even "native" apps are wrapped in a runtime (the `NativeActivity` is a thin form of `Activity` which knows to call your native code based on your meta data.) The framework provided APIs written in Java are more extensive and robust than native code. The `ServiceConnection` callback is tricky and you wouldn't be able to directly do it in native code.  You'd have to extend `NativeActivity` and write your own to "hook" to get down via JNI to your native code.